# Google Sheets: Importrange function

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I've been trying to Consolidate the Data from multiple sheets using `importrange`.
This is the formula I have. The data of multiplesheets are first name, last name, department, branch and email address.

```
={IMPORTRANGE("File 1","Sheet1!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("File 2","Sheet1!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("File 3","Sheet1!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("File 4","Sheet1!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("File 5","Sheet1!A:Z")}
```

This is the formula that I am using but its not working.

any suggestion?

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("File1","Sheet1!A:Z");IMPORTRANGE("File2","Sheet1!A2:Z");IMPORTRANGE("File3","Sheet1!A2:Z");IMPORTRANGE("File4","Sheet1!A2:Z");IMPORTRANGE("File5","Sheet1!A2:Z")},"where Col1 is not null")
```

the same result,  but if i tried to isolate each file individualy Its seems to be working without issue.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to paste each `IMPORTRANGE` formula separately and invoke **`#REF!`** error which will popup **Allow access** button. then you use a formula:

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-1", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0);
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-2", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0);
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-3", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0);
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-4", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0);
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-5", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0)}
```

---

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-1", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0)\
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-2", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0)\
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-3", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0)\
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-4", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0)\
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL-5", "Sheet1!A1:Z"), "where Col1 is not null", 0)}
```

Comment: maybe locale then... try 2nd formula

Comment: The first formula works it seems that one of the source sheet is corrupted when i recreate the sheet it works well ..thanks a lot